# Spring batch and quartz running job status

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I am using spring batch 3.0.2 and quartz 2.2.1 . Both using their meta tables as provided by both API. Spring batch job is scheduled by quartz and invoking on scheduled time. There is all information in both Quartz and Spring batch tables.

Now I would like to get the job running status which is schedules by quartz. I am not able to figure out , how can I relate quartz job key with spring batch. So that I can find the running status spring batch job scheduled by quartz system.

Can someone please help me on this? I can provide if there is any other information required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jwatch api and parse the JSON response as per requirements on JSP page.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jwatch/wikis/RESTfulAPI.wiki